# Not understanding how Backbone works

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I am new to Backbone. I was creating a very simple project consisting of 2 views and got it working. But have difficulty understanding its working behind the scenes.

**Consider this:**

1. I have two Views : First view will show up when the app is loaded (which will show a  button got from a template). and on clicking the button in the first view, the second view will be rendered showing some dummy text (again got from a template).
2. I am not using any models/collections in this app.
3. All the files are stored in the local Web Server(Apache Tomcat).

**Scenario**

I load the app. In the console, I see all files being got using HTTP GET. I now see the first View which has a button. I now shut the web server and clear browser cache. Without refreshing the browser, I click on the button. I see some dummy text in the second view.

**Questions:**

1. When the app loads, Where will all JS/HTML files get stored.? Because I see that Backbone is a client side MVC and in my case there wouldn't be any server calls. How will the browser render different views (All info has to be stored somewhere, right?).
2. I thought the answer to my first question would be browser cache. But considering the scenario above, how is it that I saw the second view even after clearing the cache?

**Thanks for taking time to read such a long question.**

**Note**: Not posting any codes since I have no issues with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is stored in memory and manipulates the Document Object Model (DOM) to create new HTML that gets displayed (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM). By modifying the DOM, you're able to change what the user sees.

If you think about "normal" programming, every time to put data into an array, it doesn't get written to disk: it's stored in RAM and you access it using the handy abstraction we know as an array (but which is just a sequence of bits in RAM).

The same thing happens with client-side apps: every time you do soemthing it doesn't necessarily get persisted (i.e. sent to a server): things can be stored in memory, and we use a handy abstraction called the DOM to manipulate these things without going crazy.

The browser cache is (as its name implies) a cache: the browser looks there for things first to save time, but otherwise fetches the data "normally". Think about making a sandwich: if you're still hungry, you'll leave out the knife, bread, etc. thinking "maybe I'll make another one soon". That way, if you do want another sandwich, you'll save time because everything is ready for you.

But if you want to make a sandwich and the knife and bread aren't already sitting out, no problem: you'll just get them out from the cupboard. It won't stop you from having a sandwich. The browser cache works the same way...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Love the sandwich analogy!

Answer (score 0):

1. The files are stored in memory, mainly you requested javascript code that will be on hold until you execute it, and when executed it will manipulate the DOM and render the appropriate views.
2. Browser cache works differently, say you refresh the browser again (if you haven't clean the cache as you did before) you will notice that the app will load faster than before, because the browser will load the files that are stored in cache instead of waiting for the server response.